# Enlarge/Shrink element on click in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an unordered list where each li is a little "tile" that expands and collapses (using animate() )  with a click. I've got it to where the li will enlarge, but I can't figure out how to shrink it back down again.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
 ul#tiles {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
width:300px;
}
ul#tiles li {
float:left;
width:72px;
height:72px;
border:1px solid black;
background:#09F;
margin:10px;
overflow:hidden;
 }
ul#tiles li a { 
}

</style>




<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.closed a").click(function(){
        $(this).parent()
            .animate({height:"300px"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .animate({width:"300px"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .animate({backgroundColor:"#fff"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .attr("class","open")
        ;
        $(this).text("Close");
    }); // closes click on "li.closed a"
    $("li.open a").click(function(){
        $(this).parent()
            .animate({height:"72px"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .animate({width:"72px"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .animate({backgroundColor:"#09f"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .attr("class","closed")
        ;           
        $(this).text("Open");
    }); // closes click on "li.closed a"
}); // closes document ready function
</script>



</head>
<body>


<ul id="tiles">
<li class="closed"><a href="#">Open</a><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li class="closed"><a href="#">Open</a><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li class="closed"><a href="#">Open</a><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li class="closed"><a href="#">Open</a><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li class="closed"><a href="#">Open</a><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li class="closed"><a href="#">Open</a><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is something like Accordion implemented in jQuery UI?

Answer (score 1):

Check the text to decide whether to open or close it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.closed a").click(function(){
        if($(this).text() == "Open"){
        $(this).parent()
            .animate({height:"300px"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .animate({width:"300px"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .animate({backgroundColor:"#fff"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .attr("class","open")
        ;
        $(this).text("Close");
        } else {
        $(this).parent()
            .animate({height:"72px"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .animate({width:"72px"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .animate({backgroundColor:"#09f"},{duration: 400, queue: false })
            .attr("class","closed")
        ;           
        $(this).text("Open");
      }
    }); // closes click on "li.closed a"
}); // closes document ready function
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ae6dX/)

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be completely optimized in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "li.closed a", function () {
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .animate({
               height: "300px",
               width: "300px",
               backgroundColor: "#fff"
            })
            .attr("class", "open");
        $(this).text("Close");
    }); // closes click on "li.closed a"
    $(document).on("click", "li.open a", function () {
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .animate({
               width: "72px",
               height: "72px",
               backgroundColor: "#09f"
            })
            .attr("class", "closed");
        $(this).text("Open");
    }); // closes click on "li.closed a"
}); // closes document ready function
```

Note the followings:

- `animate()` also accept an object of properties to animate
- 400 milliseconds is the default timing (usually identified by "normal"), so it can be omitted

You can run the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/4QmLV/

Comment: That's beautiful! I knew I had to use .on, but I had my syntax wrong. Now, I also want all the other "tiles" to close when I open a new one. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Let's retrieve all li different from the current one :)

Comment: @PatrickJ.Riepe I initially had `on` as well in my answer but then i revised it since you don't have to use it at all. Just one handler is enough and you can generalize a lot of your code. Also if at all going with `on` do not bind it to the document, instead bind it to the container eg id of the ul `#tiles` that exists in DOM at any time.

Comment: Aurelio you have to give me a bit more than that...I'm totally new at this one ;-)

Comment: I know, I know, but I'm still not seeing it. I tried running the "close" code again inside the block where you open the tile, but that, of course, closed the tile you just opened. Aaack!